# Use original class variable in an Extension that conforms to a Protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I have a situation where I want to be able to use an existing field from a class to satisfy an extension to the class that specifies a protocol.  Something like this:

```
class SomeThing {
    var foo: String
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var foo: String { get }
    func someOtherMethod()
}

extension SomeThing: MyProtocol {
    func someOtherMethod() {
    }
}
```

But the compiler is throwing errors in the file that defines the extension, that `SomeThing` doesn't fully conform to the protocol.  Is there a way to make this work so that the extension just grabs the original object's value?

Comment: Compiles fine for me after adding a `init(foo: String) {self.foo = foo}` to `SomeThing`.

Comment: ... or by providing an initial value for the foo property. – A [mcve] and the full error message from the Report navigator would be helpful.